# How to deal with an empty argument in Java?

Tags: java

I have a simple program which read the argument parameters and output them as a result.

for example, if i use:

```
Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(1.0, 2.0, "RED", false);
System.out.println(r1);
```

should return:

```
1.0 x 2.0, color: RED
```

But what if I entered the following argument:

```
Rectangle r8 = new Rectangle();
System.out.println(r8);
```

How can my program output the following default result when the above argument is used ?

```
1.0 x 1.0, filled with RED
```

Here's a part of my code:

```
public class Rectangle extends Shape {

    protected double width;
    protected double length;

    public Rectangle() {
        super();
    }

    public Rectangle(double width, double length) {
        super();
        this.width = width;
        this.length = length;
    }

    public Rectangle(double width, double length, String color, boolean filled) {
        super(color, filled);
        this.width = width;
        this.length = length;
    }

    public double getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(double width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public double getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(double length) {
        this.length = length;
    }   

    public double getArea() {
        return (width * length);
    }

    public double getPerimeter() {
        return (2 * (width + length));
    }

    public String toString() {
        if (super.isFilled()) {
        return width + " x " + length + ", " + "filled with RED";
        } else {
        return width + " x " + length + ", " + "color: RED";
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use if (width = 0){} for width but since it is a primitive type so it doesn't work...can anyone tell me how can I print out the default value if a empty argument is used ? help will be  appreciated...Thank you!

Comment: `if (width == 0) {` - comparison, not assignment.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "empty" argument.

Answer (score 12):

You can set the default values in the parameterless constructor :

```
public Rectangle() {
    super("RED", true);
    this.width = 1.0;
    this.length = 1.0;
}
```

Or you can assign default values in the declaration of the members :

```
protected double width = 1.0;
protected double length = 1.0;
```

and have a similar declaration with default value for the `Shape` members.

Or you can call a different constructor from the parameterless constructor, as suggested by Seelenvirtuose :

```
public Rectangle() {
    this(1.0, 1.0, "RED", true);
}
```

Comment: Better: `public Rectangle() { this(1.0, 1.0, "RED", true); }`

Answer (score 1):

You should always set a value in your constructor for the object properties. In your case you can define your default constructor to recall the one with parameters and passing it the default values:

```
public Rectangle() { 
    this(1.0, 1.0, "RED", true);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the problem , but this might help , if you want something else just say

```
public Rectangle() {
    this(1.0,1.0,"RED",true);
}

public Rectangle(double width, double length) {
    this.width = width;
    this.length = length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may define defaults in your constructor

```
public class Rectangle extends Shape {

    private final double DEFAULT_WIDTH=1.0;
    private final double DEFAULT_LENGTH=1.0;
    private final String DEFAULT_COLOUR="RED";
    private final boolean DEFAULT_FILLED=true;

    protected double width;
    protected double length;

    public Rectangle() {
        this(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_LENGTH, DEFAULT_COLOUR, DEFAULT_FILLED); 
    }

    public Rectangle(double width, double length) {
        super();
        this.width = width;
        this.length = length;
    }

    public Rectangle(double width, double length, String color, boolean filled) {
        super(color, filled);
        this.width = width;
        this.length = length;
    }

    public double getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(double width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public double getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(double length) {
        this.length = length;
    }   

    public double getArea() {
        return (width * length);
    }

    public double getPerimeter() {
        return (2 * (width + length));
    }

    public String toString() {
        if (super.isFilled()) {
        return width + " x " + length + ", " + "filled with RED";
        } else {
        return width + " x " + length + ", " + "color: RED";
        }
    }
}
```